# How to remove extra padding from a byte64 encoded string?

Tags: c, rsa, public-key-encryption

I found similar post [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22296/remove-padding-cbc-from-decrypted-text), but that did not help me. So, I'm posting a new question.

I have a 1024 bit "private.pem" file generated by OpenSSL. My goal is to perform an AES encryption followed by AES decryption operation.

I read "private.pem" file and add the necessary padding like the following,

```
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 16
#define KEY_BUFFER_SIZE 992

unsigned char * buffer = 0;
long length;
FILE * fp = fopen ("private.pem", "rb");

if (fp)
{
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    length = ftell (fp);
    fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    buffer = malloc (length);
    if (buffer)
    {
        fread (buffer, 1, length, fp);
    }
    fclose (fp);
}

// padding the buffer to make it multiple of 16
if(strlen(buffer)%AES_BLOCK_SIZE == 0){
   printf("No padding needed\n");
}else{
   int k=AES_BLOCK_SIZE-(strlen(buffer)%AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
   printf("padding needed: %d\n", k );
   char ch[k];
   for (int i=0;i<k;i++){
       ch[i]='0';
}
strncat(buffer,&ch,k);

printf("After padding: Wish to see 0 here in output, strlen(buffer)/AES_BLOCK_SIZE is  %d\n", strlen(buffer)%AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
printf("Padded buffer is \n %s\n", buffer);
printf("Padded buffer size \n %d\n", strlen(buffer));
```

Output is:

```
Size of Buffer is 986
padding needed: 6
After padding: Wish to see 0 here in output, strlen(buffer)/AES_BLOCK_SIZE is  0
Padded buffer is 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,28BE619B36FB04DC12A4118B62222F14
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
000000
Padded buffer size 
992
```

Now, I encrypt this **buffer** with **aes_crypt_ecb**, from a older version is PolarSSL. After decryption, I want to remove those extra padding (000000). I did the following to do that,

```
unsigned char private_decrypt[KEY_BUFFER_SIZE]; /* buffer that will contain the decrypted key */
unsigned char private_plain_key[986];

/* 
   Decryption Operation
   .............
   I'm not adding the decryption code because it seems irrelevant here as decryption operation works fine 
*/

// coping the actual key length
memcpy(private_plain_key,private_decrypt,986);
printf("strlen(private_plain_key) is %d\n", strlen(private_plain_key));  // output should be 986
printf("Decrypted private key is --> \n %s \n", private_plain_key);
```

And My output is:

```
strlen(private_plain_key) is 990
Decrypted private key is --> 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,28BE619B36FB04DC12A4118B62222F14
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
*
```

It seems like memcpy is coping more than it supposes to.

So, I have a twofold question,

1. For a 1024-bit RSA private key, what is the actual key string length? In my understanding, it should be a fixed size of 986. Am I correct? Is it true all the time?
2. How can I remove those extra padding? I mean, without using memcpy, I can add '\0' like **private_decrypt[992-6]='\0'** assuming, the private key string length is fixed and for that, I already know the exact padding I used. **I tried this approach, but when I print the buffer, it
   shows an empty line **

Comment: "It seems like memcpy is coping more than it supposes to" isn't true. Memcpy doesn't add the null byte at the end of the string (and you don't have room for it in private_plain_key[986] anyway).

Comment: Thanks. I change it like **unsigned char private_plaintext[987]**. Seems like that garbage is gone. But there is still an empty line. Any suggestions, how to remove it?

Comment: Can you post the full output for the empty line scenario? And just to confirm, using private_plain_key[987] and strcpy now gives you the same behavior as setting private_decrypt[286]='\0', correct?

Comment: I use memcpy(). And yes, after changing the array size, I'm still getting the same behaviour. [https://pastebin.com/C7qA4p6s] here is the full output

Comment: *...In my understanding, it should be a fixed size of 986...*. No, that is wrong in general. Most implementations will reliably produce a full-size modulus of 128 bytes, but the rest of the components of the private key have essentially random values constrained by certain bounds. The net result is that the size of PEM file will vary.

Comment: `strncat(buffer,&ch,k);` this can't work because you are overflowing `buffer`. It's allocated to be exactly the size of the file and you fill it up completely with the file. Then you try to concatenate something to it but there's no space left. This also means buffer will not be zero-terminated, thus strncat will not necessarily stop at the end of buffer. You were lucky in that the byte after the allocation just happened to be a zero. This code is likely to crash at some point.